# Puzzling error with FastAPI's CORS middleware

Tags: reactjs, cors, fastapi

I'm new to FastAPI. I am having problems posting images. The console says it's a `CORSMiddleware` problem:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/images' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have also set it to allow everything, but it's still not working.

```
app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware,
                   allow_origins=["*"],
                   allow_credentials=True,
                   allow_methods=["*"],
                   allow_headers=["*"])
```

My only conclusion is that fastapi and CORS are not importing at the top in main.py correctly. Why is this happening even though they are installed?

[image]

[image]

Here is a minimum workable example. The frontend is in React.js. It's coming in as props from a file reader. In this specific instance there is only one image being uploaded.

React FormData:

```
const [image, setImage] = React.useState(null);
const [src, setSrc] = React.useState(null);

export default function PostImage(props) {
const selectedImage = (img) => {
    setImage(img);
  };

async function PostData () {
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("files", image);
let response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/images", formData);
setSrc(`http://localhost:8000/images/${response.data.id}.jpeg`);
}
return(
<img src={src} alt="" />
)
}
```

Here is the image validation in Python FastApi:

```
from typing import List
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

# import dependencies
import os
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, File, Form, UploadFile, HTTPException
from typing import Optional
from uuid import uuid4  # this is for creating image ids
import PIL
from PIL import Image as pil_image  # this is to read and save images

from database.database import get_session
from models.images import Image

router = APIRouter()

@router.post("", response_model=ReadImage)
def create_image(caption: str = Form(...), tags: str = Form(...), files: Optional[List[UploadFile]] = File(None),
                 session: Session = Depends(get_session)) -> Image:

 extension = files.filename.split(
        ".")[-1] in ("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "JPEG", "PNG")
 if not extension:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=415,
                            detail="Only accepts jpg/jpeg and png. Maybe your file extension is not specified or erroneous.")

 try:
        im = pil_image.open(fp=files.file)
        im = im.convert('RGB')

        extension = im.format in ("JPEG", "JPEG 2000", "PNG", None)

        if not extension:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=415,
                                detail="Only accepts jpg/jpeg and png. Your file seems to have the correct extension, but is in the wrong format, truncated, or corrupted1.")

        # 2a validation through verify method of pillow library
        im.verify()
        im.close()

        # 2b verification through simple transpose method which would uncover truncated images
        im = pil_image.open(fp=files.file)  # is this correct?
        im = im.convert('RGB')
        im.transpose(method=PIL.Image.ROTATE_180)

uuid = str(uuid4().hex)

    # save pillow image object
    im.save(os.path.join("images", uuid + ".jpeg"), "JPEG")
    im.save(os.path.join("images", uuid + ".png"), "PNG")

    # create a new image instance
    db_image = Image(id=uuid, caption=caption)
    # register image in session
    session.add(db_image)
    # save changes in database
    session.commit()
    # reload image from database
    session.refresh(db_image)
```

The error on the server-side occurs at "extension". "'Files' does not have a 'filename'", presumably because no file is being sent.

Comment: Is your indentation correct? If `extension = files.filename.split(` isn't indented as show in your example, the code is invalid and won't run properly. If a code error (i.e. the python console shows an error) occurs, CORS headers are not added

Comment: Yes, it was indented correctly in vs code. I guess it happened when I was copying and pasting to the question.

Answer (score 1):

FastAPI's CORS middleware [is based](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/master/fastapi/middleware/cors.py) on [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/)'s. A casual inspection of [Starlette's source code](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/master/starlette/middleware/cors.py) indicates that, when `allow_origins` contains `"*"` and `allow_credentials` is set to `True` (as in your code), then the response to the CORS request contains the following combination of headers:

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

However, the [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol) (which defines how CORS works) instructs browsers to reject this combination—because honouring it would be *very* insecure. See [this relevant passage of the MDN Web Docs about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards):

> When responding to a credentialed request, the server must specify an origin in the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, instead of specifying the "`*`" wildcard.

One way to fix the issue would be to eschew the wildcard (`*`) and allow only a limited number of origins via `allow_origins`. An alternative is to use `allow_origin_regex` instead; however, for security reasons, do escape all DNS label separators in your regexp!

Comment: Thanks, but before it was set to allow_origins=["http://localhost:3000"] with the same problem.

Comment: @Jie-LiangLin Edit your question and add the exact CORS error message.

Comment: @Jie-LiangLin You need to specify the scheme also. An origin is the triple of scheme (`http`), host (`localhost`), and port number (`3000`). Instead of `allow_origins=["localhost:3000"]`, try `allow_origins=["http://localhost:3000"]`.

Comment: Yes, that was there also, if you read the error. It's just the way that the stack overflow website formatted it without http showing.

Comment: @Jie-LiangLin Without seeing a minimal workable example, I don't think I can help you much.

Comment: okay, I will edit the question and post it soon

Comment: You don't think it's something with my vscode setup though?

Comment: @Jie-LiangLin Unlikely VS Code is at the root of this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236457/discussion-between-jie-liang-lin-and-jub0bs).

Comment: @Jie-LiangLin I don't have time for a synchronous exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot to miss a comma after 'allow_headers=["*"]' in CORS middleware.

```
app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware,
               allow_origins=["*"],
               allow_credentials=True,
               allow_methods=["*"],
               allow_headers=["*"])


app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware,
               allow_origins=["*"],
               allow_credentials=True,
               allow_methods=["*"],
               allow_headers=["*"],) <<<<<<<<<HERE<<<<<<<<
```